# async Exception not being caught

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a windows service that references the following code. My code that uses the below method contains a `try..catch` block but it doesn't seem to `catch` `RefereshTokenException` that is `thrown` in the below method. Obviously my understanding of `async` is not correct.

```
private async void RefreshTokens()
{
    try
    {
        var cognito = new CognitoApi();
        var response = cognito.TokenRefresh(_refreshToken);

        if (response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            _idToken = new AwsToken(response.AuthenticationResult.IdToken);
            _accessToken = new AwsToken(response.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            await _signIn(_credentials.SiteId, _credentials.LocationId, null);
        }
    }
    catch (NotAuthorizedException)
    {
        await _signIn(_credentials.SiteId, _credentials.LocationId, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new RefreshTokenException("Failed refreshing tokens.", ex);
    }
}
```

This is the code that calls `RefreshTokens`

```
public async void Process(QueueMessage queueMessage, Action<QueueMessage> retryAction)
{
    _processingCounter.Increment();

    try
    {
        ......
        IAwsToken idToken = authenticationService.Tokens.IdToken; //This is the code that calls "RefreshTokens" method
        ........
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Code never reaches here...
        _logger.Error("Error in ProcessMessage", ex);
    }

    _processingCounter.Decrement();
}
```

Comment: Answer... don't use `async void`, please research this

Comment: Read this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an `async void`. One of the main reasons to avoid async void methods is that you cannot handle the exceptions they throw.

Make it an `async Task` and `await` it in the caller.

Note that you then have the same issue in that caller, `async void Process(...)`

Make that an `async Task` as well and work your way up. async/await  should form a chain, from your GUI or Controller down to an async I/O call.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look in to that.

Comment: And you can't await them either.